# Code shortening in aspx page

Tags: asp.net

( I'm not native English speaker, So text may not be natural )

I'm doing localization of asp.net project.
For efficiency of language translation, I'm extracting strings in .aspx into global resource file.
( I named the resource file 'StringTable.resx'. )

In that process, strings in aspx page changes as follows :

> Before : `Admin ID`
>
> After : `<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:StringTable,
>   STR_ADMIN_ID %>">`

The 'After code' looks a little bit long, So I want to shorten that code.
( For example, remove runat="server" statement, remove Resource name, etc... )
In C/C++ case, One can use #define macro.

Is there any way to do this in .aspx page? ( not in code behind file )
Any Idea will be appreciated.

====== Below is my own answer ========================================

I'm using VS2008, So I can't use `<%:` syntax in .NET 4.0.

And I introduce my alternative solution ( I'm not sure that this is best solution )

First, I added this directive in upper portion of .aspx file.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Resources" %>
```

( I wanted to set Namespace="Resources.StringTable" to remove repetitive 'StringTable', but it was not allowed. )

And after that, I replaced

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:StringTable, STR_ADMIN_ID %>">
```

To

```
<%= StringTable.STR_ADMIN_ID %>
```

It's not perfectly clean in that keyword 'StringTable' is still exist, but it looks better than original code. :)

====== Add ========================================

But when using this method, 'Design' preview mode of Visual Studio doesn't show resource string..

So It seems that I have to return to original long code. :(

( That method works well with 'Design' mode with 'refresh' function. )

Answer (score 1):

```
<%: StringTable.STR_ADMIN_ID %>
```

...is all you need :)

This uses the new `<%:` snyntax introduced in ASP.NET 4, if you're using 2 or 3 you'll need `<%= Html.Encode(` (MVC) or `<%= Server.HtmlEncode` (WebForms)

Comment: First one is cool solution, but unfortunately our team uses VS2008.  In WebForms Case, I tried `Server.HtmlCode("StringTable.STR_ADMIN_ID")`, but it doesn't work. Can you give me precise code example? thanks.