# Alternative for using resource values in ASPX pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

For multi-language support, I'm using several resource files:

***company.en.resx***

***company.ru.resx***

***company.he.resx***

**etc. etc.**

These resource files are used as translation dictionaries.

In my ASPX pages, I represent the values stores in these files.

For instance, instead of using this:

```
<div...>
     Hello, How are you ?
     ...
</div>
```

I use the resource values like this:

```
<div...>
     <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Company,Hello %>"" />
     ...
     <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Company,How_Are_You%>" /> 
</div>
```

This works nice and smoothly, but the source code look messy, and adding text to my pages is annoying.

My question is - Is there a better way of implementing this ?

Thanks.

Comment: When you're saying that your pages look messy; are you talking about the source code you've displayed, the generated html code, or the resulting design/layout of the page?

Comment: the source code. It seems messy. The actual page looks great.

Comment: Assuming you're using VS 2008 or later, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19216105/864696).

Comment: This question is currently hard to answer; how do you evaluate how messy your source is, or how annoying it is to add texts? How would you determine the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks @Ross Presser.